# Conditional itertools.product

Tags: python, numpy, generator

Suppose I have a list of heavy objects, for the sake of arguments consider 
`x = numpy.arange(10)/10`

I created a generator via `gen = itertools.product(x,x)`, to perform some computations. The fact is that my computations are symmetric: for all `i` and `j`, `heavy_calc(x[i],x[j]) = heavy_calc(x[j],x[i])`.

Hence, I only want to compute the upper part of the matrix. How can I condition the generator to return `(x[i], x[j])` only if `i >= j` ?

Comment: [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), or [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)?

Comment: `itertools.combinations(x, 2)` is almost right, it just doesn't include the cases `i == j`.

Comment: "Conditional itertools.product" is a very inefficient way to approach most problems that can be approached that way. If you ever find yourself trying to filter the output of `itertools.product`, that's a warning sign that you should look for other ways to solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, rather than `product`:

```
gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(x, 2)
```

Note that this gives `(x[i], x[j])` tuples with `i <= j`, rather than `i >= j`. That should be fine for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I would build the generator *by hand*:

```
def gen(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for y in x[i:]:
            yield(x[i], y)
```

It gives as expected:

```
>>> list(gen(list(range(4))))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```